# Assertion failed while validating password encoded with BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have pretty simple `UserCreator` service.

```
@Service
public class UserCreator {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserCreator(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public CreateUserResult createUser(CreateUserCommand command) {
        validate(command);
        return new CreateUserResult(doCreateUser(command).getId());
    }

    private User doCreateUser(CreateUserCommand command) {
        final var user = User.builder()
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(command.getPassword()))
                .email(command.getEmail())
                .birthDate(command.getBirthDate())
                .build();
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

And I'm adding few unit tests, one of those tests validates if created user has encoded password.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserCreatorTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private UserCreator userCreator;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        this.userCreator = new UserCreator(userRepository, passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Created user has encoded password")
    void test2() {
        final var userCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(User.class);
        when(userRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(User.builder().build());
        final var command = CreateUserCommand.builder()
                .email("test@test.pl")
                .password("test123")
                .birthDate(LocalDate.of(1990, 10, 10))
                .build();
        final var expectedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(command.getPassword());

        userCreator.createUser(command);

        verify(userRepository, times(1)).save(userCaptor.capture());
        assertTrue(passwordEncoder.matches(expectedPassword, userCaptor.getValue().getPassword()));
    }
}
```

However, this test fails on `assertTrue()`, those passwords does not match.

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: `BCryptPasswordEncoder#encode` isn't deterministic. It'll include a random salt, so your `expectedPassword` and the `passwordEncoder.encode` in `doCreateUser` won't necessarily match. Use a mock `PasswordEncoder`, or (maybe not worth it) pass in a mock `SecureRandom` so both calls match.

Comment: About calling `new BCryptPasswordEncoder()` - I'm indeed calling that, but as you can see, same isntance is passed to service and used in unit test. I'm not using two different instances here.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the other part of my application, when I'm handling authentication using `BCryptPasswordEncoder` and it actually solved issue for me.

Instead of doing

```
final var expectedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(command.getPassword());
assertTrue(passwordEncoder.matches(expectedPassword, userCaptor.getValue().getPassword()));
```

I should just do

```
assertTrue(passwordEncoder.matches(command.getPassword(), userCaptor.getValue().getPassword()));
```

Now my test is passing.